# Визуализация отклонения двух scatter графиков chartjs

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, график, визуализация, chart.js

Имею два датасета для сравнения. Строю график scatter типа, с двумя сразу.

Хочу выстроить график отображающий исключительно разницу (отклонение) одного графика от другого. Пробовал выстроить Line график с разницей, но не получалось или получалася непонятный результат.

В итоге хочется получить график с пиками отклонений, где один датасет является нулевой точкой для второго.

Какой алгоритм для этого стоит использовать? Правильно ли выбирать Line график для такой визуализации отклонения ?

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<script src="https://pastebin.com/raw/h0gGwDi6"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  Promise.all([
    fetch('https://mocki.io/v1/31066895-525e-4107-aeef-1f7779a91f4d'),
    fetch('https://mocki.io/v1/b0ab6854-3984-43c8-a6a3-b70975110147 ')
  ])
    .then(async ([a, b]) => [await a.json(), await b.json()])
    .then(([data, data1]) => {
      new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: data1,
            borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data,
            borderWidth: 1
          },]
        },
        options: {
        }
      });
    })
</script>
```

Датасеты:

- https://pastebin.com/h0gGwDi6
- https://pastebin.com/LK5zDZfA

Comment: Для начала вам следует определиться с тем, что вы хотите получить. Как вы собираетесть считать разницу между датасетами, если у вас координаты `x` для точек из разных датасетов не совпадают? На ум приходят всякие слова - "интерполяция", "сплайн", "нахренаоновсёнужно" и прочие ))